# Working with ranges within SQL using XML

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got a record with the following:

```
Id  Name  Value
1   Age   0-21
2   Age   22-50
3   Age   51-75
```

I build up XML like this:

```
<Property>  
    <Name>Age</Name>
    <Value>15</Value>   
</Property>
```

I need to find the record, based on the value of, 15 in this example, which falls in the range of the table above.

This is my SQL query to get the value:

```
SELECT Input.property.value(N'./Value[1]', N'nvarchar(MAX)') FROM @Xml.nodes(N'/Input/Property') AS Input(property)
```

Comment: Could you split the Value column into two (MinValue and MaxValue)? This could be done at run time also, but will most likely kill the performance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are asking here is a query that selects the rows from the table using xml value as a filter applied to the range contained in VALUE column of the table:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (Id INT, [Name] NVARCHAR(50),[Value] NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @table SELECT 1,'Age', '0-21'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 2,'Age', '22-50'
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 3,'Age', '51-75'

DECLARE @Xml xml
DECLARE @value_from_xml int

SET @Xml='<Property><Name>Age</Name><Value>15</Value></Property>' 

SELECT @value_from_xml = Input.property.value(N'.', N'nvarchar(MAX)') 
FROM @Xml.nodes(N'//Property/Value') AS Input(property)

SELECT *
FROM  @table 
WHERE @value_from_xml 
    BETWEEN SUBSTRING([Value], 1, charindex('-', [Value]) - 1) 
    AND SUBSTRING([Value], charindex('-', [Value]) + 1, LEN([Value]))
```